# League of Legends: How do blind effects work?

Tags: league-of-legends

How do blind effects such as Teemo's blinding dart and Heimer's grenade work in League of Legends? For example, does it work against an enhanced auto-attack such as Nasus' siphoning strike?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Blind affects auto-attacks only. Instead of damage numbers, a yellow "MISS" will display instead.

Blind interacts oddly with ON-NEXT-HIT spells, like Garen's Decisive Strike and Xin Zhao's 3-talon strike. The Auto-attack damage is negated, but any spell effect still goes through.

This means, for instance, that Xin will knock your champion up on a 3rd hit, even when he's blind.

> <strike>"Blind has no effect on Lee Sin the Blind Monk."</strike>

In an April Fool's video, Riot joked that Lee Sin was immune to the effects of blind, but this is **not** the case.

Comment: Just to complete you answer regarding the specific Nasus case, Siphoning Strike [Q] is an ability, is not considered auto-attack, therefore blind does not affect it.

Comment: @Raven That's a shame that it's not the case, as it definitely would make sense flavor-wise, but I guess it would be unbalanced. :(

Comment: @FallenAngelEyes - Given that there are *very* few blind effects, I wouldn't say it would be unbalanced. I would counter, however, that having an exception to the rule is very rarely better than having no exceptions to the rule. It makes it easier for the newbies to learn, that way.

Comment: @Fallen You can flavorfully think of it that "blind" is really just a general sensory blindness, not necessary just eyesight. Same going with Corki's Phosphorus Bomb (which imparts a chance for missing, not full Blind), that kind of a big bang could throw your hearing for a loop.

Answer (score 3):

For future reference, here's a copy of the [lol wiki](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Blind#Blind) Blind article:

> ### Blind
>
> - The target will miss auto-attacks, incurring the message "Miss" above their attack target.
>
>   - Blind only mitigates the physical damage portion of an attack, including physical damage sourced from a physical on-hit effect.
>   - Other damage types and effects won't miss. See: [On-hit effects](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/On-hit_effects).
>   - Abilities that apply on-hit effects will also miss.
>   - Blind is considered a form of damage mitigation. As such, it is applied after [Thornmail's](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Thornmail) passive.
> - Does not interrupt channeling.
> - The duration is affected by crowd control reduction.
> - The effect can be removed by all cleansing effects (except for [Mikael's Crucible](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Mikael%27s_Crucible)).
> - Blind will not affect certain champion abilities.(e.g. [Riven's](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Riven) passive [Runic Blade](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Riven#Runic_Blade))
> - Champions with Blind: [Heimerdinger](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Heimerdinger), [Teemo](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Teemo) , [Quinn and Valor](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Quinn_and_Valor), [Shaco](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Shaco) (non-champions only)