# What does Teemo's Blind actually block?

Tags: league-of-legends

Suppose you have Teemo vs Vladimir or Fiddlesticks, can his Blind (Q) stop the Fiddle's Drain (E), or Vlad's Transfusion (Q)?

I did search on lolwikia but I'm still not sure about this.

Comment: This should be pretty obviouse for many reasons, which is why I downvoted it.

Comment: So people here are much like the LoL community - much more eager to criticize and show off than to actually help. Good to know.

Comment: Maybe it's better off to read the FAQ before posting here.  Arqade isn't exactly Yahoo answers.  Questions that are too specific don't help anyone, and lead to those questions getting closed.

Comment: The FAQ doesn't cover this. I couldn't have known. And it would've been much nicer of them to simply say "You're not allowed to post this kind of questions on here because of reason xyz" instead of leaving a mean comment and not helping.

Answer (score 4):

> Blind
>
> - The target will miss auto-attacks, incurring the
>     message "Miss" above their attack target.
> - Blind only
>     mitigates the physical damage portion of an attack, including physical
>     damage sourced from a physical on-hit effect. Other damage types and
>     effects won't miss.
> - Abilities that apply on-hit effects will
>     also miss.
> - Blind is considered a form of damage mitigation.
>     As such, it is applied after  Thornmail's passive.
> - Does not
>     interrupt channeling.
> - The duration is affected by crowd
>     control reduction.
> - The effect can be removed by all cleansing
>     effects (except for Mikael's Crucible).
> - Blind will not affect
>     certain champion abilities.(e.g. Riven's passive Runic Blade)
> - Champions with Blind:  Heimerdinger,  Teemo ,  Quinn and Valor,
>     Shaco(non-champions only)

Taken from [the League of legends wiki](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Blind#Blind).

Comment: @Joetjah That's not hate speech, that's just snarkiness.

Comment: It was definitely uncalled for in any case, especially towards a new user.

Comment: Sorry about that ^^

Answer (score 2):

Fiddlesticks' Drain is a channelled ability. Blind will not cancel channelling spells -- all CC except for Blind, Slow, and Snare/Root will, though.

Vladimir's Transfusion is an instant spell. Blind will not prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

No, Teemo's blind stops neither Fiddle's Drain nor Vladimir's Transfusion.

The key point here is that most normal abilities are not affected by blind.  Abilities which add effects to their attacks (Teemo's Toxic Shot, Xin's Three Talon Strike) will still work even though your auto-attacks are being missed.

Taken straight from the [lol wiki](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Blind#Blind), with relevant parts bolded:

> ### Blind
>
> - The **target will miss auto-attacks**, incurring the message "Miss" above their attack target.
>
>   - Blind only mitigates the physical damage portion of an attack, including physical damage sourced from a physical on-hit effect.
>   - Other damage types and effects won't miss. See: [On-hit effects](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/On-hit_effects).
>   - **Abilities that apply on-hit effects will also miss**.
>   - Blind is considered a form of damage mitigation. As such, it is applied after [Thornmail's](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Thornmail) passive.
> - **Does not interrupt channeling**.
> - The duration is affected by crowd control reduction.
> - The effect can be removed by all cleansing effects (except for [Mikael's Crucible](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Mikael%27s_Crucible)).
> - Blind will not affect certain champion abilities.(e.g. [Riven's](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Riven) passive [Runic Blade](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Riven#Runic_Blade))
> - Champions with Blind: [Heimerdinger](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Heimerdinger), [Teemo](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Teemo) , [Quinn and Valor](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Quinn_and_Valor), [Shaco](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Shaco) (non-champions only)

Comment: Your second point is not true. Teemo's Blind is not an ability that applies an on-hit effect. A list of abilities that apply on-hit effects can be found [here](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/On-hit_effects#Abilities_that_apply_on-hit_effects).

Comment: You caught me mid-edit fixing that.  Also, a more general version of this question can be found [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/31337/league-of-legends-how-do-blind-effects-work), but it doesn't add much content.

Comment: "Abilities which add effects to their attacks will still work" This is only true if it is a spell effect, abilities that apply on-hit effects will miss when blinded.